# Is there a pyqt5 method to convert a python string to a QByteArray?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qbytearray

this is probably a very simple question but I haven't been able to find a good answer to it yet. I've found answers for converting `QByteArray`s into python strings, but not vice versa.

Is there a pyqt5 method that allows me to simply convert a python string into a `QByteArray` (so that it can be sent over a serial connection using `QSerialPort.write()`). I reckon it's likely that there is a nice built-in feature in pyqt5 to do this without manually extracting the bytes from the string and building a `QByteArray` from them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the string to bytes:

```py
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray
>>> s = "hello world"
>>> ba = QByteArray(s.encode())
>>> print(ba)
b'hello world'
```